# How to extract submatches from a string and write those to a file?

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I want to parse a string for specific submatches and output those - one submatch per line - into a file.

Essentially I would like to extract the value of each href-attribute:

```
$ cat Fin
<a href="a.htm">A</a>X<a href="b.htm">B</a>Y<a href="c.htm">C</a>

$ echo Fin | [grep, sed, awk, ...?] > Fout

$ cat Fout
a.htm
b.htm
c.htm
```

I tried few things with named tools but things don't work or are too complicated. I would like to perform this transformation within a single command line concatenating as few as possible commands with piping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GNU `grep` (if built with PCRE support) for this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=a href=")[^"]*' file
a.htm
b.htm
c.htm
```

It is a look-behind (what's after `a href="`?) and gets everything up to next double quote.

Comment: I assume "file" is supposed to mean "Fin" - but no matter how I tweak your command - it is not going to give me the output you state.

Comment: Yes, I wrote `file` but use the name of the file you are using. Aren't you getting the correct output? If so, please indicate the system in which you are working and the output you get.

Comment: I use fish-shell and your command line yields no output at all

Comment: It might be some escaping issues. What if you try `grep -Po '(?<=a href\=\")[^\"]*' file`?

Comment: as well, no output

Comment: Then there is nothing else I can do. It is working fine on `grep (GNU grep) 2.14`, Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: It works perfectly on Fedora 17 with GNU grep 2.14 here. +1 for the more elegant version.

Comment: With  recent versions of PCRE, see also: `grep -Po 'a href="\K[^"]*'`

Comment: That's a very good answer, @StephaneChazelas , I am learning a lot from you today :)

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. I made a mistake. it does work.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's%</a>%\n%g' Fin | sed 's%.*"\([a-z]\.htm\).*%\1%' > Fout
a.htm
b.htm
c.htm
```

Surely there is a shorter, more elegant way.

Comment: I tested the code and it does not seem to work as intended. The first line of Fout is as follows: "<a href=a.htm>A"

Comment: Did you really use the exact same string as in your example? Here it works perfectly.

Comment: There was a mistake on my side of the equation

Comment: Well done! Note that `cat file | sed '...'` can be replaced by `sed '...' file`.